# Check if a specific mysql connection already exists during a php script?

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have a class for each database table object. Each class takes care of connection/queries/data format (database table specific logic) as I prefer to assign a connection for each class for better modularity. Also, I am using specific connections for some tables and queries.

My question is how can I check if a connection already exists so it won't start another one?

Basically I want to check if the connection with the same username/password/database has already been made. Or is this not necessary because mySql won't start a new connection for the same user? If that is so then please explain.

**After further research** found out that this is not possible ... it would require to get the thread id and use the conn with the thread id and it would act like a persistant conn; Or it would require to keep track every thread ids used during a script and it's kinda useless.

There isn't yet a spimple method of doing this ... persistant connection can be a choice but then u have to take care of connection clean up and again sux :)

P.S. : Eventually i did made a tracking system for the connections during my app run (the guys that said to store them in a globally available object we're right). Stored conn object and conn params in 2 arrays in a singleton class object, checked if the params allready exists in params array , if not make new conn , if yes get the conn object from the array-key thats the same with the key where params were found... I allready had the arhitecture made for this but didnt want to use that class...not the logic i began with :), and also wanted to make it in a library item, thats why i was looking for a simple and abstract solution but there is only a particular solution :)

Comment: Why do you want to handle this yourself rather than using the PHP built in persistent connection? Are you doing something special?

Comment: You can say i'm just stubborn :P ... i want to implement the p conn initial logic (chekc for existing conn) but for a normal conn ...

Comment: :-) ok. Have you thought about executing SHOW PROCESSLIST against mysql to see what users are connected?

Comment: yes and i get 2 conn for same user :| thats why i want to check first for the same conn

Comment: How about SELECT CONNECTION_ID();

Comment: i'm using this SHOW STATUS LIKE '%onn%' to see the connections... am i wrong or the connections swon arent the number of connections opened?

Comment: I dont think this is what you want http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections

Comment: ok... what i'm looking for its the thread id and yea tested , same user connects 5 times during a script

Comment: Did you check registry pattern? It's a commoN Design pattern. According to your 3rd paragraph, credentials can be key and value can be the connection.

Comment: I was searching for a simple solution like asp has ... but yea i did it like that... storing the conn object and conn params in 2 arrays and chek them when app runs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create new connection for each class is not a good idea. It may be modularized to you but your mysql server will be soon bloated with `too may connections` error.

I suggest use singleton pattern and some OO.

```
class Singleton{
    private static $instance=null;
    public function connection(){
        if(self::$instance==null){
            self::$instance = mysql_connect(); // define it in your way,
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }
}

class TableA extends Singleton{
    function find($id){
        $query="select * from `A` where `id`='$id'";
        mysql_query($query, $this->connection());
        ... // other codes
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not for each class dont worry, it's for some of them... i'm just trying to modularise the logic... but i need to keep track of the connections that are the same... ill try to find a way to make available info about conn across the app ... won't be easy , might have to change a lil bit my arhitecture

Comment: My bad every class has assigned to it a conn... thought u ment by new conn , different user (some classes have same conn some have different conn but all have a conn assiged to them)... that was my question, i need to check for allready made conn that are the same so it wont bottle up

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this - I think this will help you http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: yes basically i want to do the thing that persistant connection does...but i dont want a persistant connection...i want to implement its logic for a normal connection... i mean the first thing that the p conn checks for... if that conn exists

Answer (score 0):

If you must have a different connection for each class, you can use a static class property to hold the connection, and use the singleton pattern to retrieve it.

```
class SomeTable {
  // Connection resource as a static property 
  // Since it is static, it will be shared by all instances of class SomeTable
  public static $db = FALSE;

  // Static method to retrieve the connection
  // or create it if it doesn't exist
  public static function get_conn() {
    if (self::$db) {
      // Just return the connection if it already exists
      return self::$db;
    }
    else {
      // If it doesn't already exist, create it and return it
      self::$db = mysql_connect(...);
      return self::$db;
    }
  }

  // In other methods, use self::get_conn()
  public function someQuery() {
     $sql = "SELECT col FROM tbl";
     // Call the connection singleton explicitly
     // as the second param to mysql_query()
     $result = mysql_query($sql, self::get_conn());
  }
}
```